# How do I install the latest stable version of Redis?

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I am new to redis. and I just followed cli to install redis `sudo apt-get install redis`.
but the install server version is `2.2.12` . If I want to update this version and I want to install `redis 2.7 +` then how can I do this thing, please help. I am working on `ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: [Redis 2.4.16 is the latest stable version](http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.4.16.tar.gz)?

Comment: how can i update this version

Comment: http://redis.io/download How did this escape you?

Comment: i just dowbloaded that package and extracted it in www folder, instead of installing from command line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either compile from [source](http://redis.io/download) or build a `.deb` package via [`fpm`](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm):

Install `fpm` with `gem`:

```
# apt-get install rubygems
# gem install fpm
```

Compile Redis:

```
# cd /usr/local/src/
# wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.4.16.tar.gz
# tar zxvf redis-2.4.16.tar.gz 
# cd redis-2.4.16/
# make
```

Build `.deb` package:

```
# mkdir -p /tmp/redis-$VERSION.$$/usr/bin
# mkdir -p /tmp/redis-$VERSION.$$/etc
```

`# cp src/{redis-benchmark,redis-check-aof,redis-check-dump,redis-cli,redis-server} /tmp/redis-$VERSION.$$/usr/bin`

```
# cp redis.conf /tmp/redis-$VERSION.$$/etc/redis.conf
# cd ..
```

`# fpm -s dir -t deb -n redis-server -v 2.4.16 -C /tmp/redis-2.4.16.18597/ -p redis-server-2.4.16_amd64.deb usr/bin/`

Upgrade Redis:

```
# dpkg -i redis-server-2.4.16_amd64.deb
dpkg: warning: downgrading redis-server from 2:2.2.12-1build1 to 2.4.16.
(Reading database ... 148744 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace redis-server 2:2.2.12-1build1 (using redis-server-2.4.16_amd64.deb) ...
Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
Unpacking replacement redis-server ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/var/log/redis': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/etc/redis': Directory not empty
Setting up redis-server (2.4.16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
```

Examine the version:

```
# /usr/bin/redis-server -v
Redis server version 2.4.16 (00000000:0)
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/944216

Answer (score 1):

I installed it following this [checkinstall tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/162), the steps I followed are:

1. Install **checkinstall** and its dependencies:

   sudo apt-get install build-essential automake autoconf libtool pkg-config libcurl4-openssl-dev intltool libxml2-dev libgtk2.0-dev libnotify-dev libglib2.0-dev libevent-dev checkinstall
2. Make the package and install the .deb file

   ./configure && make && sudo checkinstall

It worked good for me.

Comment: It usually a good idea to explain the solution instead of only linking to an external site.

Comment: Yeah well, the link has a full tutorial didn't want to duplicate content, the idea is to use a utility named [checkinstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/), this utility will create a Slackware, RPM or Debian compatible package and install it with Slackware's installpkg, "rpm -i" or Debian's "dpkg -i" as appropriate, so you can view it's contents with pkgtool ("rpm -ql" for RPM users or "dpkg -l" for Debian) or remove it with removepkg ("rpm -e"|"dpkg -r")

Comment: the problem is that when that link dies your answer becomes useless.

Comment: Ah got it good point, ok thanks let me improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The redis server packages are maintained by ubuntu also. So you install using the following command

```
apt-get install redis-server
```